# Make counter in Python

Tags: python, counter

Is there a way to re-write my code using a counter?
Something like: i=0, el=name[i+1]?? As code looks too long with lots of repeatings in it

```
 name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'com.eas.android:id/text_username')))
    try:
        if name:
            action.press(el=name[0]).wait(2000).perform()
            self.delUser()
            btnBack.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            action.press(el=name[1]).wait(2000).perform()
            self.delUser()
            btnBack.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            action.press(el=name[2]).wait(2000).perform()
            self.delUser()
            btnBack.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            action.press(el=name[3]).wait(2000).perform()
            self.delUser()
            btnBack.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            action.press(el=name[4]).wait(2000).perform()
            self.delUser()
            btnBack.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            action.press(el=name[5]).wait(2000).perform()
            self.delUser()
            btnBack.click()
            time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 4):

The code could be simplified using a [for loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm):

```
    try:
        if name:
            for n in name:
                action.press(el=n).wait(2000).perform()
                self.delUser()
                btnBack.click()
                time.sleep(2)
```

Although, I would be careful as `name` seems to be a [list](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists), yet you are using it like a [bool](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/boolean/) in the if-statement on line 2. (Correction: this is fine. See randomir's comment)

Comment: Try `bool([])` and `bool([1,2])`. Non-empty lists in Python are truthy.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
        if name:
           for i in range(6):
              action.press(el=name[i]).wait(2000).perform()
              self.delUser()
              btnBack.click()
              time.sleep(2)

  or

        if name:
           for i in range(len(name)):
              action.press(el=name[i]).wait(2000).perform()
              self.delUser()
              btnBack.click()
              time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: `range[0,5]` is invalid syntax, I think you meant `range(5)`, but to include the last value you should actually use `range(6)`

Comment: Or possibly, to keep it general `range(len(name))`.